# Why linux perf report addresses even beyond kernel space?

Tags: linux-kernel, symbols, perf

I collected some perf data (mostly `mysqld` process) via
`sudo perf record --cpu 14-17,78-81 -a --call-graph lbr`

Then I did `perf report`,
but I saw some very strange addresses reported by Linux perf and could not resolve them to any known symbols.
**Does anyone know these address and what they are?** Thanks.

These addresses are even beyond highest **kernel symbol addresses** on my machine.

```
# kernel symbol address
ffffffff85430000 B _end
ffffffff85600000 D __init_scratch_begin
ffffffff85600000 d sme_workarea
ffffffff85a00000 D __init_scratch_end
```

`ffffffffa64000aa` from `perf` is even higher than
`ffffffff85a00000 D __init_scratch_end`
[image: Strange addresses in first few lines]

Comment: It's used by the AMD SME memory encryption code https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.15/x86/amd-memory-encryption.html

Comment: @stark Thanks for your answer. I am on Intel platform. I am not sure Intel has this feature. Do you know how to check it on Intel platform?